# Applying sizeof() to an element in const char *array[]

Tags: c

This works perfectly:

```
#include <unistd.h>

const char error[] = “Not enough arguments\n”;

int main(void)
{
    write(2, error, sizeof(error));
    return (0);
}

Output: Not enough arguments
```

However in this case sizeof returns the size of a pointer instead:

```
#include <unistd.h>

const char *error[] = {
    "Not enough arguments\n",
    "Malloc failed\n",
    "Etc...\n",
    NULL
};

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (error[i])
    {
        write(2, error[i], sizeof(error[i]));
        i++;
    }
    return (0);
}

Output: Not enouMalloc fEtc...
```

Obviously I could just use strlen or printf or a plethora of other solutions. But I am mainly wondering if it’s doable with sizeof(), yet without explicitly declaring its size (char error[4][12] for example).

Comment: No, it's not possible. The elements of `error` are pointers, not arrays.

Comment: For the first example: almost perfectly, or +1 byte; `sizeof(error)` returns 22, covering the array's 21 bytes shown + null terminator; try piping the output to `cat -v` or `xxd -g 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of possible, but not simple. You can define a struct like:

```
struct error_st {
    char * msg;
    size_t msg_len;
}
```

Make a macro like:

```
#define ERROR(msg) {msg, sizeof(msg)}
```

Then your error list becomes:

```
struct error_st error_list[] = {
    ERROR("Not enough arguments\n"),
    ERROR("Malloc failed\n"),
    ERROR("Etc...\n"),
    {NULL, 0}
};
```

Usage is:

```
write(2, error_list[i].msg, error_list[i].msg_len);
```

Maybe not worth it with an extra struct and macro, and extra fields if you're never going to use them elsewhere. You can make the struct part of the declaration, but I often find I eventually need to make it separate eventually, and you're still left with that extra macro:

```
#define ERROR(msg) {msg, sizeof(msg)}
struct error_st {
    char * msg;
    size_t msg_len;
} error_list[] = {
    ERROR("Not enough arguments\n"),
    ERROR("Malloc failed\n"),
    ERROR("Etc...\n"),
    {NULL, 0}
};
```

Comment: Similar to the OP's first example, `sizeof()` string literal accounts for the null terminator; each `write()` output from this example would include a null byte at the end; check with `cat -v` or `xxd -g 1`

Comment: This is super clever, I love it!

Comment: You're right. That's the size you'd want for copying, but not for writing. You could change the macro to store sizeof()-1.

Answer (score 3):

sizeof is an operator (not a function) that evaluates its operand at compile time not at runtime (except in the case of variable length arrays). The type of the element in the array is `char*` hence why you're getting that result.

Note that there is an exception to the compile time restriction on sizeof. C99 and Cxx11 allow sizeof to be computed at runtime for variable length arrays.

Comment: If `sizeof` is evaluated at compile time, how does `#include <stdio.h>` / `int main(void) {int n; scanf("%d", &n); int a[n]; printf("%zu\n", sizeof a); }` work?

Comment: @EricPostpischil there's in exception in c99 and cpp 11 for variable length arrays.

Comment: So it is not always evaluated at compile time?